# libvlc for Android: video decryption 'on the fly'

Tags: encryption, aes, libvlc, exoplayer, vlc-android

In my Android app I have encrypted video files saved in the app's directory (in the filesystem). My goal is to play the video without its previous decryption and saving decrypted file in the filesystem. Is it possible to do it with libvcl library for Android? I've embedded it into my app and read the docs but could not find a way to decrypt video 'on the fly'. If not, what is the best Android library to achieve this?